# Google forms check unique e-mail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have got problem. How check inputed field in form on finding in spreadsheet?
Example:
User input e-mail in TextItem field.
If inputed mail there is in spreadsheet, user sees error. "This e-mail is alredy used".
P.s: sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Are you using a Google Form?  Sorry, but you will need to provide more information, and a good question should include code that you have already tried.

Comment: Yes, i using Google Forms, my problem is i dont know how make this code, i read documentation about google app script, my Google Forms - it's simple registration to university olymp, form include field "e-mail", i want to restrict 1 email = 1 user. If inputed e-mail was registered early - user sees error text. I dont understand how to make this( thank for you comment!

Comment: I think that there is a setting in the Google Form to restrict submissions to one per Google account.  That will only work if the user has a Google account and it signed in.  There is a check box for:  **Limit to 1 response** in the General tab of the Form Settings.  If you need a custom solution, then there is no direct way to achieve this because you can't stop a Form submission except with the **Limit to 1 response** feature.

Comment: Thank's, i looking it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Forms are not able to validate user input by comparing it to external data.

One alternative is to use Google Apps Script to update the validation rule but your list could be too large.

Another alternative is to use a drop down instead of short text question.

Comment: Thank for the answer!) Idea with Google Apps Script - interested me. Can you show me simple example with   "update validation rule"?